# Assigning particular classes to particular counties via a function - D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to write a function that will assign certain county IDs a certain class. I've written functionality using `onclick` but that was utilizing the DOM element. Below is a trimmed version of the code, the output is not assigning the class of blue, it's just removing the existing class and turning the county black:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1hcdcym/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.c550000 {
    fill: blue;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

.counties .hovered,
.counties :hover {
    fill: #ffffff;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

.county-borders {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #F0F8FF;
    stroke-width: .2px;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.state-borders {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #162955;
    opacity: .8;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    pointer-events: none;
}

</style>

<svg class="map" width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var path = d3.geoPath();

d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
    if (error) throw error;

        var jsonCounties = us.objects.counties.geometries;

        function loadCurrent() {
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonCounties.length; i++) {
                if (jsonCounties[i].id == 32007) { //Random county id for testing
                    var geoCounty = us.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(d) {return d.id == 32007;});
                    us.objects.counties.geometries = geoCounty;

                    var county = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties);

                    svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "c550000") //apply this attribute to this county
                        .selectAll("path")
                        .data(county)
                        .enter()
                        .append("path")
                        .attr("d", path);
                }
            }
        }

        loadCurrent();

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "counties")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "state-borders")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.nation).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path);
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "state-borders")
            .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.nation, function(a, b) {
                return a !== b;
            })));
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "state-borders")
            .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
                return a !== b;
            })));
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "county-borders")
            .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) {
                return a !== b;
            })));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are trying to achieve but this will make the path blue:

```
       svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "counties")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "c550000") //apply this attribute to this county
        .attr("d", path);
```

You should though use data binding to do this - I would structure the data such that the county would be part of the data so I could write the class assignment line like this:

```
.attr("class", function(d) { return d.county.name }) // just an example
```

If you need to set more than one class consider using: 
[selection.classed](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_classed)

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to draw all the counties but assign a particular class to just one based on some condition, then simplify to this:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "counties")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .classed("c550000",function(d){
    return d.id === "32007";
  });
```

If you only want to draw that one county and class it, simplify to this:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "counties")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
  .enter()
  .filter(function(d){
    return d.id === "32007";
  })
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .classed("c550000", true);
```

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

I would make it very data-driven, something like:

```
var classMap = {
 "class1": [41015, 02150, 44007],
 "class2": [45085, 06107, 17127],
 "class3": [37147, 17127, 06107],
 "c550000": [32007]      
};

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "counties")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .each(function(d){
    for (var key in classMap){
      if (classMap[key].indexOf(+d.id) !== -1){
        d3.select(this).classed(key, true);
      }
    }
  });
```

Here's running code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var path = d3.geoPath();

d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
    if (error) throw error;
    
      var classMap = {
        "class1": [41015, 02150, 44007],
        "class2": [45085, 06107, 17127],
        "class3": [37147, 17127, 06107],
        "c550000": [32007]      
      };

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "counties")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .each(function(d){
              for (var key in classMap){
                if (classMap[key].indexOf(+d.id) !== -1){
                  d3.select(this).classed(key, true);
                }
              }
            });

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "state-borders")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.nation).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path);
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "state-borders")
            .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.nation, function(a, b) {
                return a !== b;
            })));
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "state-borders")
            .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
                return a !== b;
            })));
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "county-borders")
            .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) {
                return a !== b;
            })));
});
```

```css
.c550000 {
    fill: blue;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

.class1 {
    fill: blue;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

.class2 {
    fill: red;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

.class3 {
    fill: green;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

.counties .hovered,
.counties :hover {
    fill: #ffffff;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

.county-borders {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #F0F8FF;
    stroke-width: .2px;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.state-borders {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #162955;
    opacity: .8;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg class="map" width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response mark! The final goal is to assign one of 10 classes to all counties on the map. Sorry, should've specified. Will the above code still apply on a macro scale in a for loop?